# What is the Black Box?

Tags: .hack

I was reading on the Wiki about the [Vagrant AI's](http://dothack.wikia.com/wiki/Vagrant_AI) and it said that most were born from The Black Box.

I've seen //SIGN, //Liminality, //Legend of the Twilight //Terminal Disk, //ROOTS, //QUANTUM and played the original 4 games and the 3 //G.U games and i've never heard of the Black Box before, i am wondering what this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black box is the portion of The World's systems that Harold Hoerwick designed before his death. CC Corp is, for unstated reasons, unable to ever modify or remove it without messing everything up (I'm being general on purpose). Every version of The World is built on this black box in some way.